# How to use InAppSettingsKit delegate to reconfigure changed app settings

Tags: ios, xcode, inappsettingskit

I am using [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) to include preferences inside my app. I configured the preferences view using xcode's **storyboard** with the following simple steps:

1) I created a navigation controller and a table view controller 
2) In the table controller I used the custom class: IASKAppSettingsViewController, as the controller.

Everything works as expected BUT now I am trying to reconfigure the app so that the settings that the user changed take effect after leaving the settings screen.

One tutorial I found says that I should:

> Create a delegate that conforms to the IASKSettingsDelegate protocol.
>   In the current version, -settingsViewControllerDidEnd: is the only
>   required method.

so the delegate should have a method like:

```
- (void)settingsViewControllerDidEnd:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self reconfigure];
}
```

How can I create this delegate? I do not know where to put this method. I can see in the storyboard connection inspector that there is a space for the delegate but I have not been able to connect it. Please help me figuring this out because I have read tons of tutorials explaining delegates and they confused me more. I just need simple steps on how to create a delegate and connect it to the controller I created in the storyboard.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have made some advances (**but there is one problem**). This is what I did:

Instead of using IASKAppSettingsViewController as the class of my controller, I created another class that inherits from IASKAppSettingsViewController. I called it SettingsController

SettingsController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IASKAppSettingsViewController.h"

@interface SettingsController : IASKAppSettingsViewController <IASKSettingsDelegate>
- (void)settingsViewControllerDidEnd:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender;
@end
```

SettingsController.m

```
...
@implementation SettingsController
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
    self.showDoneButton = YES;
}
- (void)settingsViewControllerDidEnd:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender {
    // reconfigure code here
}
@end
```

So basically, I did not make any delegate connection using the storyboard. I had to write `<IASKSettingsDelegate>` in the controller, and used `self.delegate = self;` in viewDidLoad method.

The thing is that for the reconfiguration to work, I would need the main view controller to be the delegate (not the settingscontroller). I have not been able to do that. Any help?

**Second try:**
Ok, so now I trie using:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"settingsSegue"])
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

But it does not work. I believe it is because the destinationViewController is a navigationController in the storyboard that immediately displays the table view controller where the settings are.